# mysql, selective WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I face the situation where I need a WHERE clause to act different once and I don't know how to solve.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE

      (
      CASE @test
      WHEN 0
        THEN
          pid = inPID
      WHEN 1
        THEN
          id = inPID
          @test := 0    <- syntax error
      END
    )
```

I tried to define some @test variable (which is initialized by procedure parameter) and if the procedure is called with TEST=1, I need id=inPID just once. This is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

try do it like that

```
  @test =  @test - 1
   -- this just to be @test is 0 , if you have other value change  it be 0
```

**EDIT:**

try this

```
  (
  CASE @test
  WHEN 0
    THEN
      pid = inPID
  WHEN 1
    THEN
      id = inPID
  WHEN 1
    THEN
      @test := 0    
  END
```

**or** use this

```
  WHEN 1
THEN
  id = inPID AND  @test := 0
```

Comment: No, the problem is I can write 1 line between THEN and END, but more lines would give me error. I tried to imbrication into BEGIN END but no success. I use dbForge Studio...

Comment: nope, is not working, actually is not evaluated. I guess modifying is made AFTER the SELECT...

Answer (score 1):

Can you give this a try? It's best if you could show us the entire query statement though. In `CASE THEN` you can use `AND`, `OR` in SQL Server though, test this out anyway.:-

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE

      (
      CASE WHEN @test = 0 THEN pid = inPID
           WHEN @test= 1 THEN id = inPID AND @test:=0
      END
    )
```

Comment: @user1973900 have you tried this one out? Please comment and glad to hear how it goes.

Comment: thanks for answer (both) but  WHEN @test= 1 THEN id = inPID AND @test:=0 is making ALWAYS @test=0 (and of course the first time that I need), so is not working

Comment: Please clarify a bit more. I got the impression that you want to reset `@test` to `0` when its initial value is evaluated as `1`. Happy to help you if you could explain :)

Comment: Well, I solve it somehow... when @test=0, SELECT returns 10 values but when @test=1, just 1 row was returned so the query terminate and @test have no chance to get other value. I changed strategy. Thanks again,

Comment: `:D` thanks for sharing :) and glad you got it worked out. Why don't you post your answer in that case. It's allowed to post your answer.